# can boost::bind be used with references without copying?

Tags: c++, boost

Following code shows that the parameter, passed by reference, is copied when using boost::bind.  Is there a way to prevent the copying without resorting to pointers (which I currently use as workaround)?  (tested with gcc 4.4.3)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void function1(int& x)
{
  std::cout << "function1 &x: " << &x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int y = 0;
  std::cout << "main &y: " << &y << std::endl;

  boost::function<void()> f = boost::bind(function1, y);
  f();
}
```

Comment: For any function that must be used in `bind` (or similar parameter lists) I use only pointers. It prevents the accidental copying which is often very hard to debug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use boost::ref for passing references to boost bind.

```
boost::function<void()> f = boost::bind(function1, boost::ref(y));
```

Comment: thanks, this helps.  Unfortunately these things are always a bit more difficult than expected...

Comment: I just realised that I can't use this, because I have put the bind in templated functions, where I don't know that the parameter is a reference.  Ah well, I'll use pointers.

Comment: stefaanv: I could only answer from what I saw in your question

Comment: @stefaanv: To address this problem you can use simple structure in Boost.CallTraits style, e.g.
template<class T> struct param_type { typedef T type; };
template<class T> struct param_type<T&> { typedef boost::ref<T> type; }; (Or I missing something ?)